# Formatting Parameters section of the report in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, parameters, formatting

I have several parameters on an SSRS report.  There are two groups of these parameters.  One group is report specific, the other group is data specific.  I would like to be able to seperate these two groups of paramaters for ease of use.  Is it possible to introduce formatting into the Parameters section of an SSRS report?  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. Best you can do is to just change the order of the parameters so the report parameters are the top few rows and the data parameters are lower. Then perhaps change their names to include a prefix.

You could build your own parameter page and format it as you choose, but it can't replace the built-in page in the Report Manager.

EDIT:
URL example mentioned in comments:

```
http://servername/reportserver?%2fFolder%20Name%2fReport%20Name&rs:Command=Render&Parameter1Name=Value1&Parameter2Name=Value2
```

The first parameter on the querystring is the report manager path to the report. It's URL encoded so / becomes %2f and space becomes %20. [This MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms153563.aspx) has more info.

Comment: Roger that....that's what I thought.  When you say "build your own parameter page".  How is something like that implemented?  That sounds interesting.....

Comment: Well there are a couple of options. One is to just build a page that calls the report via querystring parameters. The URL would look something like the example I added to the question above. (formatting doesn't work right in comments)

Another option if you're building ASP.NET is to add the Reporting Services Web Service as a Web Reference and call its methods to render the report output in a stream. That's a bit more involved but it'd give you greater control over the output.